# How to distribute identical balls in different boxes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, balls-in-bins

600 identical balls must be randomly distributed into 6 numbered boxes. What is the probability of exactly 300 balls ending up in the first three boxes? Note that all balls must be distributed but boxes can be empty.

I think I have solved it but I don't know if it is right since the way I solved it looks wrong, but let me explain how I did it. So what we have here is combinations with repetitions, we have 600 to distribute in 6 different boxes and we can put as many balls as we want in Box 1 but the criteria we have is that exactly 300 should be in the first 3 boxes. Totally we have C(6+600-1,600-1). Step 2: How many ways can we divide 300 balls in  the first 3 boxes, C(3+300-1, 300-1). In how many ways can we divide 300 balls in  the last 3 boxes, C(3+300-1, 300-1). We use multiplication principle and then just divide favorable outcomes by the total number of outcomes ? Is it right?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), especially the parts under the first bullet.

Comment: What did you obtain for the total?

Comment: You appear to be using Stars and Bars, but that doesn't seem like an appropriate method.  Keep in mind that the patterns counted by that method are not equally probable.  Hint:  a binomial distribution is all you need here.

Comment: "...Totally we have C(6+600-1,600-1)..." : As asked by @N.F.Taussig, please explain where this came from.  Also, it would help me to understand your thinking if you explain the signficance of (for example) the expression $C(n,k)$.  Are you attempting to represent (for example) $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(k!) \times [(n-k)!]} ? $$  If not, what does $C(n,k)$ represent to you?

Comment: Per the comment of @lulu, see [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Comment: Even if you are given identical balls, they can be labeled to distinguish them.

Comment: **Food for thought:** Does the answer to the Probability problem change if the balls are not to be regarded as **identical**?  Here, I distinguish between a Probability problem and an **enumeration** problem.  You are not being asked to enumerate all of the different (equally likely) ways that the identical balls can be distributed.  Instead, you are being asked to compute a Probability, which may be regarded as something that looks like $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

Comment: Per the last comment of @N.F.Taussig, and my last comment, since this is a Probability problem, rather than an enumeration problem, **if** you **pretend** that the balls are **not identical**, the answer to the Probability problem will **not be changed**.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I got 6.64353676×10^13 for the total

Comment: What we have been trying to convey to you is that you can treat the balls as if they were distinct.  Therefore, there are six choices for each of the $600$ balls, so there are $6^{600}$ possible distributions.  For the favorable cases, you can use the Binomial distribution.  What is the probability that a given ball lands in one of the first three boxes?

Answer (score -2):

I agree with [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu), [user2661923](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464411/user2661923) and [N.F.Taussig](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173070/n-f-taussig) that you can treat the balls as numbered and use the binomial distribution. Thus, the answer is
$\binom{600}{300}(\frac12)^{600} \approx 0.0325599$

A Monte Carlo simulation (see python 3 code below) gives: $0.03256$

```
import random, math
successes=0
numtries=100000
for tries in range(numtries):
    boxes=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for boll in range(600):
        boxes[random.randrange(6)]+=1
    if(boxes[0]+boxes[1]+boxes[2] == 300):
        successes+=1
print("Monte Carlo:", successes/numtries)
print("Exact:", math.comb(600,300)*0.5**600)
```

Comment: Even if you are offering this as a simulation, you should provide what you get as output and offer a judgement on what it says about the answer of the Question you responded to.  As you likely know, a Monte Carlo simulation will typically be run a number of times so that the results can be averaged in some way.  You might also offer an opinion on whether with a comparable amount of work get an exact answer.